# Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class?

Tags: php, datetime

Using the `DateTime` class, if I try to run the following code:

```
$mydate = new DateTime();
echo $mydate->date;
```

I'll get back this error message

> Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date...

Which doesn't make sense because when running `var_dump()` on the variable `$mydate`, it clearly shows that this property exists and is publicly accessible:

```
var_dump($mydate);

object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2012-12-29 17:19:25' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

Is this a bug within PHP or am I doing something wrong? I'm using PHP 5.4.3.

Comment: Good question. I thought for a moment that I didn't understand...anything.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382).

> Date being available is actually a side-effect of support for `var_dump()` here – derick@php.net

For some reason, you're not supposed to be able to access the property but `var_dump` shows it anyways. If you really want to get the date in that format, use the [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function.

```
echo $mydate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Why wouldn't one want this exact format? It is the same format as MySQL has for dates.

Comment: This is the same if using var_dump or print_r.

Answer (score 19):

Update: The behaviour has changed in PHP7.3, the original answer doesn't work anymore. To get the same results with all PHP versions, incl. >=7.3, you can use the following code:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v');
```

---

For the record, the original answer:

Besides calling `DateTime::format()` you can access the property using reflection:

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime();
$o = new ReflectionObject($dt);
$p = $o->getProperty('date');
$date = $p->getValue($dt);
```

This is slightly faster than using `format()` because `format()` formats a timestring that has already been formatted. Especially if you do it many times in a loop.

However this is not a documented behaviour of PHP, it may change at any time.

Comment: How this stopped working in PHP 7.4? 7.2 version
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38d86c07d4c50ee12b8c0a47e82ef6ffc0327592
7.4 - Error
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38d86c07d4c50ee12b8c0a47e82ef6ffc0327592

Comment: @TechCare99 :) I think it should never worked like this, it was a hack. Need to check 7.4 for an alternative, not doing much php nowadays but will check it. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Updated to work with [all PHP versions](https://3v4l.org/3tc31)

Answer (score 5):

The date property of DateTime is protected.

You can display the date with format function.

```
<?php

try {
    $time = new DateTime();
    echo($time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Or you can convert to array:

```
<?php

try {
    $time = (array) new DateTime();
    var_dump($time["date"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Comment: He wanted to know why couldn't he access the date property of DateTime object... Where do you see he wanted to format a stored Datetime values ? "Y-m-d H:i:s" is the format in witch the date is by default !

Comment: Object to array conversion - as you suggest - is probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by the other answers, it is an issue with PHP which is unresolved as of today but if it is a 'side effect' of `var_dump()` I am not so sure..

```
echo ((array) new DateTime())['date']; // Works in PHP 7.
```

What I am sure about is that *if* the properties of `DateTime` where meant to be used by us it would have been made available. But like many internal classes they are *not* and you shouldn't rely on "hacky" or "glitchy" methods to fix your code. Instead you should use their [API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If you are not satisfied you can extend the class or perhaps use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) that extends it for you.

```
echo (new Carbon())->toDateTimeString();
```

If you wounder how `var_dump()` creates a fake output of an object take a look at [`__debugInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo)

Answer (score -2):

If you just use a **var_Dump** before ask the property date everything works allright:

```
$mydate = new DateTime();
var_Dump($mydate);
echo '<br>';
echo $mydate->date;
```

This delivers:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-04-11 08:44:54.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" }
2017-04-11 08:44:54.000000
```

So you see the property date exists even for the object. I can't understand this behaviour. Just comment out the var_Dump and you will get the error again.

Comment: error_reporting(0);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($mydate->date));

Comment: No it doesn't, certainly not in php7, throws a `Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date`