# Fetch current date and time only in PHP

Tags: php

I want to fetch only date and time from this object:

```
$current=new DateTime
```

Will display:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-06-06 17:35:08 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Singapore )
```

I want to fetch only `date`. How can I do that? I tried `$current->date` but got an error message:

```
UUndefined property: DateTime::$date
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class? Is it a bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the current date you need to do something like this:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

See more information at [documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Answer (score 0):

To fetch Current date and time in PHP you can to try this...

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
echo "Current Date is" . date("d-m-Y") . "<br>";
echo "Current Time is " . date("h:i:sa");
```