# Have not access to the element of object without var_dump at front

Tags: php, object, var-dump

I'm having a very strange problem. The thing is, that I can't access anything from the variable `$conDat["_RenewalDate1"]` unless I use an `var_dump` of it upfront.

With this code:

```
var_dump($conDat["_RenewalDate1"]);

$test = $conDat["_RenewalDate1"] -> date;
var_dump($test);
```

I get the desired output.

But without this line:

```
var_dump($conDat["_RenewalDate1"]);
```

It just returns NULL.

What could possibly be the cause of this strange problem?

Additional info:

This code:

```
echo "first var_dump: <br />";
var_dump($conDat["_RenewalDate1"]);

$renewalDate1 = $conDat["_RenewalDate1"] -> date;
echo "<br />second var_dump: <br />";
var_dump($renewalDate1);
```

output:

```
first var_dump: 
object(DateTime)#47 (3) { 
    ["date"] => string(26) "2015-10-11 00:00:00.000000" 
    ["timezone_type"] => int(3) 
    ["timezone"] => string(3) "UTC" 
} 
second var_dump: 
string(26) "2015-10-11 00:00:00.000000"
```

and this:

```
echo "first var_dump: <br />";
// var_dump($conDat["_RenewalDate1"]);

$renewalDate1 = $conDat["_RenewalDate1"] -> date;
echo "<br />second var_dump: <br />";
var_dump($renewalDate1);
```

output:

```
first var_dump: 

second var_dump: 
NULL
```

Comment: What is the output of the var_dump then?

Comment: It must return something otherwise you wouldn't be able to access a property from NULL

Comment: So in the first bit of code does var_dump($test) return anything or is it just the second var_dump that returns something (other than NULL)

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump($conDat)` ?

Comment: @ТарасКостюк edit the question, please.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14084222/3933332

Comment: Mathlight,  Rizier123, mfisher91, sitilge, qquestion updated. Please check you may find their additional info.
@Cosmin, yes I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$conDat["_RenewalDate1"]` is a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. You're attempting to use an undocumented property that is only ever made available due to [a side effect.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382)

> ->date being available is actually a side-effect of support for var_dump()

---

Use [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) instead.