# Very "interesting" behavior of a DateTime object and access to its elements - bizarre

Tags: php, date

### I don't consider this a duplicate, per say, since the other question speaks of var_dump not print_r. I think others might run into the issue using print_r and thus they would find my question and the answers and might miss the other questions. I did, not find the other one, that is.

I was writing some code to calculate a date by subtracting a number of days from the current date. I got the current date with the `getdate()` function. I then used `date_sub()` to subtract the days.

While testing I had some problems and so I put in some `echo` and `print_r()` statements.

I finally got it working as I wanted and I took out the `echo` and `print_r()` statements.

When I ran the code I got an error: E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: DateTime::$date -- at line 8

The statement in question was a reference to the DateTime object's date element. I thought that perhaps I had screwed up when I commented out the `echo` and `print_r()`statements so I undid the changes and tried it - it worked with no error.

I then very carefully removed the `echo` and `print_r()` stagements and tried it again - bang! same error.

I sat and stared at the screen for awhile and began to figure out which `echo` and `print_r()` statement was preventing the error. I finally narrowed it down to one print_r() that displayed the DateTime object. If I left it in, no error occurred and the output was correct. If I commented it out - the error occurred.

I did some more staring and then went to find out what another way to reference the DateTime object's data element. I found i could get the same results with object->format()

But the bizarre behavior has a grip on me and I came here to present it and see if anyone has any theories as to why it is happening.

Here's the bare minimum coded needed to demonstrate the issue

```
<?php
    $today = date_create();
    print_r($today);
    echo '<br>';
    print_r($today->date);
?>
```

It is the second statement - `print_r($today);`- which somehow allows me to access the date element as $today->date without an error.

The output will be something like:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-12-22 21:00:34.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )

2015-12-22 21:00:34.000000
```

If you comment out that statement, you'll get:

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: DateTime::$date -- at line 5
```

You probably are having trouble believing this - go to fiddle.org and play with the code.

Comment out the first print_r() and you get the error. Un-comment and you don't get an error.

If you replace the `print_r()` statement with with one that does not reference the DateTime object, such as `print_r('Hey there');` -- you will get the error. It is not the print_r() function itself, it is the `print_r()` call with the DateTime that somehow prevents the error.

So - any thoughts on what that `print_r()` statement is doing that enables the "incorrect" reference to the DateTime object's data element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class? Is it a bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug)

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known [issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382):

> ->date being available is actually a side-effect of support for var_dump() here. I'll mark this as a feature request as it was not intended to work.
>
> derrick@php.net

You are supposed to print DateTime with `->format()`:

```
echo $today->format("Y-m-d H:m:s");
```

Comment: Ah - I don't get your point. I didn't what to display the DateTime object, I had put in the print_r() statements to see what was happening, not as part of the actual functionality. Also, print_r() does work if you don't go after an individual element but only specify the object itself.

Comment: @SimonT `->date` is private, but the bug after using `print_r`/`var_dump` makes it public