# Object property not showing

Tags: php, datetime, var-dump, getid3

I have a function on a php page that is intended to grab the creation date/time of video files using getid3.  I thought everything had been working fine and was ready to put this version to bed when I was (of course) running everything one more time to make sure and ended up with an issue I just can't seem to figure out.

The relevant bit of code is this:

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($file);
if ($ThisFileInfo["quicktime"]["moov"]["subatoms"][0]["creation_time_unix"]){
    $createdate = new DateTime("@".strval($ThisFileInfo["quicktime"]["moov"]["subatoms"][0]["creation_time_unix"]));
}
else {
    $createdate = new DateTime("@".strval($ThisFileInfo["quicktime"]["moov"]["subatoms"][0]["modify_time_unix"]));
}
$createdate->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
//var_dump($createdate);
$createdate = $createdate->date;
```

When I process a file using this portion I get an error stating `Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in … line 179`(file path removed by me).  However, I know that this isn't the case because if I uncomment the `var_dump` line listed above I get the output `object(DateTime)#3 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-01-24 15:20:32.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" }`.

It certainly looks to me like the DateTime object `$createdate` has a property called `$date`, so I'm not sure what's going on, though I'm assuming it's something in my syntax. Can someone help me to sort this out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug TLDR `$createdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not sure which variables are accessible from your current scope of an object, you can use **[get_class_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php)**.

Using it on a DateTime object returns an empty array:

```
var_dump(get_class_vars(get_class($datetimeobj)));
```

...which means the `$date` property is private one. Of course, you can access the string representation of the DateTime object with the **[date_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php)** method:

```
$dateString = date_format($dateTimeObj, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can read more on the format syntax [in the "date" manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Thank you! I think that would have taken a good while to figure out!

Comment: No problem, also check @Steve 's answer, it's a little bit simpler approach than yours. Cheers!