# Strange behaviour when accessing objects

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $date1->date. ' while echoing date1';
```

It echoes only " while echoing date1", in other words `$date1->date` is empty.
If I add dump date1 first like this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var_dump($date1);
echo $date1->date. ' while echoing date1';
```

I get

```
object(DateTime)[359]
  public 'date' => string '2016-06-26 16:54:56.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

`2016-06-26 16:54:56.000000 while echoing date1`

which is what I want. This thing is getting me mad as it is completely unexpected.

Comment: var_dump($date1); is outputing 2016-06-26 16:54:56.000000 that's why they are different

Comment: `var_dump()`....:):) remove and check

Comment: I'm not sure if this is simply asking why this is happening or if you are trying to figure out how to use DateTime?  You should be using `echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` not relying on the `$date` property.  You'd have to look into the code of the DateTime class, but I'd assume that the `$date` property isn't filled by the constructor or format method.

Comment: I need to know how to access the date property without doing the dump first

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php  does not seem to have `->date`, so I don't understand why in the second example the output will come out

Comment: @Ferex Try once more and see if that is really the case

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy you are true, I didn't write `->date()` but `->date` which DateTime object has in it's properties

Comment: Well, I didn't realized that, thanks for the link

Comment: I don't think it's worth a downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format option isn't for setting the format of the object, it's a method that returns the date object as a string in the requested format:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

To clarify, what you see as a 'date' within the object is just a text representation for convenience, as internally it will be held in an optimized way.  If you want to add it to a string, you need to specify the format you want:

```
echo "This is the date ".$date->format('c');
```

Comment: If that is the case why would the first one not outputting?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy, not really a phenomenon.  No where in the manual does it suggest to use the `$date` property, you'd just need to see when the `$date` property is getting set in the class.

Comment: Yes but why I can access the property only after dumping the object?? Isn't it strange??

Comment: @Devon sorry I've changed the comment

Comment: @Ferex, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug.  From a quick glance, the `$date` property is just provided for debugging.