# PHP Issues with DateTime in array from JIRA api

Tags: php, datetime, jira

I'm trying to get data out of JIRA and into a table. I have got the API request working and I have got almost all the data out of JIRA and into the table that I need, I just can't seem to get the created date out as it is in a datetime object within the array and doesn't have a proper format.

```
    foreach ($ret->issues as $issue)
    {
            $date = new DateTime($issue->fields->created->date);
            $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$issue->fields->status->name.'</td>
                <td>'.$date.'</td>
                <td>'.$issue->fields->priority->name.'</td>
                <td>'.$issue->fields->summary.'</td>
                <td>'.$issue->fields->assignee->displayName.'</td>
                </tr>';
    }
```

That is the PHP code for building the table, as you can see I've tried to format it with DateTime.

Here is the array if I die on $issue->fields->created

```
    object(DateTime)#318 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2018-10-22 12:47:02.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(1)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(6) "-04:00"
      }
```

I just can't seem to get that data out as $issue->fields->created->date shows me:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DateTime as array
```

Which is why I tried to format it as above. Now I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DateTime::$date
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$date = $issue->fields->created;` ? It appears to already be a DateTime object.

Comment: It does, I need to use that data but I don't know how to.

Comment: Looks like you could just use `$issue->fields->created->format('Y-m-d')` inside your `echo`

Comment: @rickdenhaan, please set that as the answer and I will vote for it! I had tried this method but I did $issue->fields->created->date->format('Y-m-d') which failed.

Comment: I've voted for that, thanks very much! can I use the timezone to get it to display in UTC at the same time?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer.

Comment: [Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug)

Comment: That's awesome @rickdenhaan, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$issue->fields->created` is already a `DateTime` object. To format that as `Y-m-d` format, you can simply call `format()` on that directly:

```
echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$issue->fields->status->name.'</td>
    <td>'.$issue->fields->created->format('Y-m-d').'</td>
    <td>'.$issue->fields->priority->name.'</td>
    <td>'.$issue->fields->summary.'</td>
    <td>'.$issue->fields->assignee->displayName.'</td>
</tr>';
```

If you want to convert it to a different timezone, you can do that as well:

```
$issue->fields->created->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"))->format('Y-m-d')
```