# PHP get sub value of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2019-01-28 08:19:44
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Asia/Jakarta
        )
)
```

And PHP:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $rowsintimespanAccept; $i++)
{
    $a = array();

    $a[] = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $linesAccept[$i]);
    if(count(array_filter($a)) == count($a))
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($a);
    }
}
```

Now my question how to get `[date]` value?

I tried using this code but got empty.

```
print_r($a['date']);
```

***UPDATED***

Now I have this array value:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-01-28 08:21:01
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Jakarta
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-01-28 08:21:14
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Jakarta
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-01-28 08:19:44
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Jakarta
)
```

and PHP:

```
for($i = $readRowAfter; $i < count($linesAccept); $i++)
{
    $dateobjAccept = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $linesAccept[$i]);

    if($dateobjAccept < $toDateTime && $dateobjAccept > $fromDateTime)
    {
        $rowsintimespanAccept++;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dateobjAccept);
}
```

Tried using this:

```
print_r($dateobjAccept->format('Y-m-j H:i:s'));
```

But only got result: 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `print_r()` to see inside the `DateTime` object outputs it like an array, but because it's an object, you can't simply access it like an array.

You can extract a date in any given format using `DateTime::format()`, so in your case `$a[0]->format('Y-M-j H:i:s')` will display the date/time in the same format as you're seeing in the `print_r()` output.

Source: [Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class? Is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug)

Comment: Awesome, got it now. Cheers

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted! :)

Comment: Hi... I just got issue still in this case. Please have a look on my updated post

Comment: Could you please update the code snippet to be complete with the variables you are using? This will help see exactly what values are going in to the function arguments.