# Why did PHP Datetime sub function stop working on PHP 7.1?

Tags: php, phpunit

It's finally time to make the jump! The below code used to work on PHP 5.6

I move to 7.1, and it's failing. What am I doing wrong?

```
$expectedToday = new DateTime();
$expectedToday->sub(new DateInterval('PT5H'));
$this->assertEquals($expectedToday, functionThatReturnsDateTimeSuccessfully()));
```

I get

```
Failed asserting that two DateTime objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 2019-03-15T08:35:21+0000
```

So functionThatReturnsDateTimeSuccessfully is plainly working.

However, when I comment out the second line

```
$expectedToday = new DateTime();
// $expectedToday->sub(new DateInterval('PT5H'));
$this->assertEquals($expectedToday, functionThatReturnsDateTimeSuccessfully()));
```

I get

```
Failed asserting that two DateTime objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-2019-03-15T13:38:31+0000
+2019-03-15T08:38:31+0000
```

So my question is - what am I doing wrong? Why does sub appear to empty the contents of the whole DateTime object? If this function's borked why don't they deprecate?

--- **UPDATE** ---

The same issue does **not** occur with add. This is just with sub.

Comment: What does a simple `var_dump` of `$expectedToday` give? Note that both assertions are *failing*, and that the first assertion gives no clear `---` expected or `+++` actual output, so it's hard to clearly pin the failure on `sub`…

Comment: The first gives a +++, just not a --- . That's the odd thing. It's like Sub is NULLing out the internal vars, or something.

Comment: Can you show 'functionThatReturnsDateTimeSuccessfully' too?

Comment: Incredibly strange. `sub` looks consistent [here](https://3v4l.org/MgMCr)

Comment: Off-topic, and I assume it's just a typo—but there's an extra closing parenthesis in your `assertEquals()` call

Comment: Updating from one dead version of PHP (5.6) to another dead version of PHP (7.1) does not really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check reference link [Why can't I access DateTime->date in PHP's DateTime class? Is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084222/why-cant-i-access-datetime-date-in-phps-datetime-class-is-it-a-bug)

So to resolve this issue, you should get date with setting its format as below:

```
$expectedToday = new DateTime();
$expectedToday->sub(new DateInterval('PT5H'));
$this->assertEquals($expectedToday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "2019-03-10 15:15:15");
```

Hope it helps you.